Authorize IAP to send traffic to Cloud Run
After configuring IAP for Cloud Run, login works but then after that I get a 403 http status saying that:

The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated
invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional
troubleshooting documentation can be found at:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client

Following the documentation links and for my needs, I ended up in this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run#turning_on
All the steps are done except the last one that suggests adding the cloud run invoker role to the IAP service account, but the problem is that SA doesn't exist in my project's IAM. And I don't have enough role to create that identity with this command:
gcloud beta services identity create --project PROJECT_ID --service iap

Any suggestions ?

the SA was not visible in the console, but was present so I just had to give it the the invoker role, and then it started to show in the console, after activating Google provided role grants checkbox

Please be specific where you are looking. A service account will not appear under IAM & Admin -> IAM until granted a role via a policy binding but will appear under Service Accounts. The only principals that will appear under IAM are principals that are part of a project's IAM policy.

Did you grant this SA service-[PROJECT-NUMBER]@gcp-sa-iap.iam.gserviceaccount.com  the cloud run invoker role?

@JohnHanley yes that's the case I was looking in IAM and it didn't showup until I gave it the cloud run invoker role. Guillaume: yes It's working now, however, it's another subject but the token part is not very clear in the documentation (ie: how to get/send a token to the backend from spa, all I see is a Cookie right now)

The SA for IAP is present by default but it doesn't show up until you grant it at least one role, so using the gcloud CLI was the solution.
